# How to throw an ArgumentNullException before calling other constructor

Tags: c#, syntax, exception, constructor

I have a question related to the syntax of constructors and throwing exceptions inside the constructor.

How to throw an ArgumentNullException for argument b before the call to CreateAnotherOne() and throw the exception as in the 2nd constructor without duplicating the code after the checks? I could extract the code into a separate private method but I need to call it from both constructor bodies... is there an other option to achieve this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IWhatEver a, ISomeThingElse b)
        : this(a, b != null ? b.CreateAnotherOne() : null)
    {
        // or should I call :this(a, b.CreateAnotherOne()) instead? this could cause a NullReferenceException => how to verify that b is not null?
        // don't want to call CallMeFromConstructor() instead of call to other constructor

        // would not do the following (why should I check a/c twice?) and the check is too late here (because already called a method on b, b.CreateAnotherOne())
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
        }

        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        }
    }

    public MyClass(IWhatEver c, IAnotherOne d)
    {
        if (c == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("c");
        }
        if (d == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("d");
        }

        // the cool code comes here, I could put it into
        // the CallMeFromConstructor method but is there another way?
    }
    ...

    private void CallMeFromConstructors()
    {
        // the cool code could be here, too (but is there another way?)
    }
```

If I call the 2nd constructor with : this(a, b != null ? b.CreateAnotherOne() : null) I would get an ArgumentNullException for d int the 2nd constructor. This sounds strange to me and could be misleading because I called the first one (can see this only in the stack trace).

The problem is that I can't write

```
:this(a, b == null ? b.CreateAnotherOne() : throw new ArgumentNullException("b"));
```

and if I put the check into the body of the constructor it gets checked to late in this case.

**Any syntactic sugar ideas to solve this?**

Comment: // or should I call :this(a, b) instead? That's what I would do

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you describe the *behavior* you want, instead of describing the constructors?

Comment: @Haxx can't do this because the 2nd param is an other type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A private method would do it, but you could make another private constructor as well:

```
    private MyClass(IWhatEver a)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
        }

        // the cool code comes here, I could put it into
        // the CallMeFromConstructor method but is there another way?
    }

    public MyClass(IWhatEver a, ISomeThingElse b) : this(a)
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        }
    }

    public MyClass(IWhatEver a, IAnotherOne b) : this(a)
    {
        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice idea and this keeps the code from beeing called twice, thx